# Java code highlighting does not support underscores in numeric literals

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

In Java 7, a new feature was added to Java that [allows underscores to be placed within numeric literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) in order to improve the readability of them. However, the Java code highlighting on SO is not properly treating numeric literals with underscores as numeric literals.

Right now, Java numeric literals show up as red to stand out from what surrounds it. However, when an underscore is used in such a numeric literal, only the part to the left of the first underscore is highlighted as red; the rest of the number is just black. Whenever this new feature is used in SO code, it should be the *entire* numeric literal that is highlighted, not just the first part of it.

Since the author of Prettify does not seem to update the project that often, this is a request for someone to upload a patch to fix it. Once that is done, I'll change this request to one that asks SE to update to the newer revision.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26102093

Screenshot:
[image: Underscore issue example]

Comment: Related: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) tl;dr: StackExchange uses Google Prettify. When someone fixes it in Google Prettify, it'll be fixed here.

Comment: Reported it here to track it. Will report there when I get a chance.

Comment: Relevant issue on Prettify's issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=353

Comment: Hahaha. Numeric literals? For C#, half of features don't work (and if they do, they're working wrong) and no one gives a damn. Even something as simple as XML highlighting fails in deeply nested files.

Comment: What an odd feature...

Comment: @canon, I wish it were more common. First saw it when using Ada in 1991. http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/ada-gem-7/ And I know Eiffel supports numeric literals with underscores. https://docs.eiffel.com/book/method/eiffel-programming-language-syntax#Integers

Comment: @Athari You should report those issues like damryfbfnetsi did here, and you may find those problems resolved in the near future.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance: It's gaining on, Rust has it too for example.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Ruby also has it. Its use is recommended by a very [popular Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#underscores-in-numerics).

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Why someone would want to write `1_000_000` instead of `1E6` is beyond my understanding.

Comment: @Roland it'd look too similar to IE6!

Comment: It would make more sense for `0x3B9A_CA00` although I don't know if that's valid in Java (`0x3B9A'CA00` is valid in C++14)

Comment: @MSalters It's valid code.

Comment: @Roland I do.  I'm visual; For example, I have trouble reading digital clocks and far prefer analog (the shape of the hands rather than the specific numbers is how I tell time), and numbers in general are the same way.  I can see at a glance that the first one is 1 million, but with the second one I have to do some quick math to figure it out.  It's trivial math, but it is enough to break the flow.

Comment: @MSalters Looking at the examples in the docs linked in the question, that appears to have been the intent behind adding the feature

Comment: @Roland One, 1E6 is a double not an int. Two, how would you abbreviate 1_234_567?

Comment: @JohnKugelman If I had to hardcode such a number (which is kind of unusual in my work) I might write `1.234567e6` (or `1.234567e6L` if I needed an integer) in R. I don't use Ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 9/24/2020, the Stack Exchange network (including Stack Overflow) has switched from Prettify to highlight.js, per [this announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter).  This change of renderer fixed this issue.

The following demonstrates the new, working rendering:

```java
public void myMethod() {
  int number = 123_456;
  int number2 = 123;
}
```

Here is a side-by-side image comparison of the two syntax highlighters:

[image: highlight.js & Prettify comparison]